# Can't access every object property in Twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a `News` entity with the next properties:

- text
- start_date
- expire_date

Here's part of the class:

```
//News.php

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=200)
 */
private $text;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
private $start_date;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
private $expire_date;
```

I want to show all the news in a list in a twig template, this is how I'm doing that:

```
<div class="list-group">
    {%for news in news%}
        <div class="panel panel-default">
         <div class="panel-heading">{{ news.start_date|date('Y-m-d') }}</div>
         <div class="panel-body">
            {{ news.text }}
         </div>
        </div>
    {%endfor%}
</div>
```

The fact is that I get the following error:

```
Neither the property "start_date" nor one of the methods "start_date()", "getstart_date()"/"isstart_date()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "AppBundle\Entity\News".
```

But If I try to render only the `text` property, I am able to access it.

Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your attribute is private. you can add a `getter`

```
public fucntion getStartDate() {
  return $this->start_date;
}
```

and in twig

```
{{ news.startDate|date('Y-m-d') }}
```

Comment: use startDate instead of start_date

Comment: Ok, it worked with startDate. The underscore was causing the error. Thanks!

Comment: It is because twig strip the "get" of the getter. Happy that helped you